# jQuery textarea replace carriage returns with plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input with text that user paste in it. And I have to find all carriage returns chars and **replace it with plain text "\n"**. "\n" should be visible in output textarea. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zmf7ztyk/)

I wrote the code, but output area display my "\n" as HTML tag and make it carriage returns again. But if I use text func I can't carriage returns chars. Please help.

```
$("#convert").click( function () {
    var txtValue = $('#input').val();
    $('#output').html(txtValue.replace(/\r?\n/g, "\n"));
});
```

`#input` and `#output` are textfields.

Comment: Can you post here your full code? Or, even better, create a **working** [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply escape the backslash:

```
$('#output').html(txtValue.replace(/\n|\r/g, "\\n"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use additional slash to put a "\n" in the string, like this:

```
$("#convert").click( function () {
    var txtValue = $('#input').val().replace(/\n/g, "\\n");
    $('#output').html(txtValue);
});
```